# Convert a text file into a list

Tags: list, text, python-3.x

This is what my text file consists of:

"I like ice cream very much"

So far this is my code:

```
f = open('nums.txt', 'r')
list = []
data1 = readline()
print (data1)
```

This is the output:
    `I like ice cream very much`

I was wondering how I could get it so each word is separated e.g. `['I', 'like', 'ice', 'cream', 'very', 'much']`

I am working in Python 3.3. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [str.split method](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
print(data1.split())
```

---

```
>>> data1 = 'I like ice cream very much'
>>> data1.split()
['I', 'like', 'ice', 'cream', 'very', 'much']
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't think it would be something that simple!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corresponding one-liner:

```
print(open("nums.txt").read().split())
```